# select previous record for a group of Ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id, id_employee, hours FROM WorkHours WHERE hours > 8;
```

How to select a previous employee work record for every one that was selected by this query?

So, for table like this (id, id_employee, hours):

```
1 - 1 - 5
2 - 2 - 3
3 - 1 - 9
4 - 1 - 4
5 - 2 - 4
6 - 2 - 10
7 - 2 - 7
8 - 1 - 7
9 - 2 - 9
```

Records 3, 6, and 9 will be selected. I also what to get records 1, 5, 7. Basically, for every time someone worked overtime, I want to see how many hours this person has in previously recorded day.

Comment: what is meant by "previous employee work record"?

Comment: for each returned id the previous id for the same id_employee

Comment: show your data and expected result.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I have a bag of potatoes. How do I make a bicycle?

Comment: Can u explain what output you want

Comment: @maSTAShuFu done. Basically, for every time someone worked overtime, I want to see how many hours this person worked on previous work day.

Comment: you said you want to get 1,5,7 also. tell us what is the logic to get those rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the previous `id` using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT wh.id, wh.id_employee, wh.hours,
       (SELECT MAX(wh2.id)
        FROM WorkHours wh2
        WHERE wh2.id_employee = wh.id_employee AND wh2.id < wh.id
       ) as prev_id
FROM WorkHours wh
WHERE wh.hours > 8;
```

Then, to get the full row, use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT eh.*, wh.*
FROM (SELECT wh.id, wh.id_employee, wh.hours,
             (SELECT MAX(wh2.id)
              FROM WorkHours wh2
              WHERE wh2.id_employee = wh.id_employee AND wh2.id < wh.id
             ) as prev_id
      FROM WorkHours wh
      WHERE wh.hours > 8
     ) eh LEFT JOIN
     WorkHours wh
     ON wh.id_employee = eh.id_employee;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be SELECT MAX(wh2.id)?

Comment: @Sergi0 . . . Yes, thank you (or alternatively `ORDER BY wh2.id DESC LIMIT 1`).